# How to pre-fill function arguments?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, closures

I have a module that attaches event listeners such as this:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', handleClick));
```

However, when the `handleClick` function is invoked, I want to automatically pre-fill the arguments with an auth token if it exists. So, I have a `withAuth` function that does the following:

```js
const token = 'token';

const withAuth = (fn) => {
  return (...args) => {
    console.log('args is ---', [...args, token]);
    fn.apply(window, [token, ...args]);
  }
}

const handleClick = (...args) => {
  console.log('handle click called----', args);
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', withAuth((e) => handleClick(e, 'Soham')));
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

<sup>Press F12 to view console output; event objects are not handled well by Stack Overflow's console formatting</sup>

Why am I able to access the event object in the `handleClick` function even though the first console correctly captures the event object? Am I doing something wrong? What is the best way to achieve such functionality?

Comment: So you mean to do `document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', withAuth(handleClick));`?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: I have updated the code

Answer (score 1):

the `e` in `withAuth((e) => handleClick(e, 'Soham')))` doesn't receive the Event object,
the event object is passed to the callback function, which is this case, the returned function from `withAuth`, so on printing `args` there you can see the Event object,
then you are calling this passed function `(e) => handleClick(e, 'Soham')` by passing some parameters `[token, ...args]`, but in the function you are receiving only the first argument `(e)`,

so you can fix this by having `(token, event) => handleClick(token, event, 'Soham')`

or just `(...args) => handleClick(...args, 'Soham')`

```js
const token = 'token';

const withAuth = (fn) => {
  return (...args) => {
    console.log('args is ---', [...args, token]);
    fn.apply(window, [token, ...args]);
  }
}

const handleClick = (...args) => {
  console.log('handle click called----', args);
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', withAuth((...args) => handleClick(...args, 'Soham')));
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```